# IE 9 work around for jQuery and .focus();

Tags: jquery

Hi I have the following JQuery code for setting the focus on the only text input within a form

```
$("#search-field").focus();
```

It works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but in IE 9 the page loads, the cursor blinks once in the input box and then stops and it loses the focus, the element from the form is below.

```
<input  autofocus type="text" id="search-field" name="search-field"  class="searchInput"  />
```

Comment: have you tried removing this `autofocus` attribute.

Comment: It works but it still seems to take ages before the focus is set, and adjusting the value from 1000 doesn't seem to make much difference. I should mention that the for opens after being expanded in a div with JQuery, would this make a differrence?

Answer (score 0):

That's because IE 9 renders the Input after running the focus function.

Here is a workaround by a Timeout-Function:

```
setTimeout(function() { $('#search-field').focus(); }, 1000);
```

And I guess if you call the .focus function in the window.onload or document.ready function it'll work too:

```
$(document).ready( function ( ) {
  $('#search-field').focus( );
});
```

Comment: Of these options, I would recommend document.ready, since we can never know for sure the rendering time of the page.